# Search and replace unix command line, perl capture group empty

Tags: regex, bash, perl, unix, sed

I'm trying to perform a recursive search and replace of file content in multiple files.

Given the below in a number of files:

```
example:{
  something: 'ha',
  somethingElse: 'ah'
}
```

I'd like to end up with:

```
example:{
  something: 'ha',
  somethingElse: 'ah',
  somethingNew: 'ah ha'
}
```

On Mac OS X, I am trying the following from command line from within a parent directory:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -p -i -e "s/somethingElse:(.*)/somethingElse:$1,\n\tsomethingNew: 'ah ha'/g" {} \;
```

It's almost working except the capture group is interpreted as blank resulting in:

```
example:{
  something: 'ha',
  somethingElse:,
  somethingNew: 'ah ha'
}
```

What's the problem?

Also not tied to `perl`, I don't mind an alternative approach (can use `sed` for example)

Comment: You need to use single quotes. The $1 is interpreted by bash before perl, therefore it is empty when perl sees it. Or just escape it, as you use single quotes in your replacement. `\$`

Comment: thanks @123 that's also an alternative fix

Comment: Looks a bit like JSON or another structured data format. Is it? Because if so, regular expressions are probably not the tool for the job.

Comment: Sorry can't go into specifics. If it were JSON though and you had say 500 files you just wanted to tweak in a small way, why not regex? What else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4923629/123) for [answer in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700448/search-and-replace-unix-command-line-perl-capture-group-empty#comment62875168_37700448):

> You need to use single quotes. The $1 is interpreted by bash before perl, therefore it is empty when perl sees it. Or just escape it, as you use single quotes in your replacement.

Thus translating to:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -p -i -e 's/somethingElse:(.*)/somethingElse:$1,\n\tsomethingNew: '\''ah ha'\''/g' {} \;
```

or:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -p -i -e "s/somethingElse:(.*)/somethingElse:\$1,\n\tsomethingNew: 'ah ha'/g" {} \;
```

It might also be wise to add a file extension when doing this, one guess why: you may perform accidentally from too high a directory and corrupt say version control files, i.e.

```
find . -type f -name '*.json' -exec perl -p -i -e "s/somethingElse:(.*)/somethingElse:\$1,\n\tsomethingNew: 'ah ha'/g" {} \;
```

The originally accepted answer which was deleted suggested `\1` rather than `$1`. Whilst this worked it was noted as [bad practice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-%5c1-Instead-of-%241) by other commenters.